# PHP relative path for includes

Tags: php

So maybe I'm not getting how PHP includes work.
I have a file structure like this:

```
app--|
     |
     -classes-|
              -PHPMyClass.php
     |
     -includes-|
               -PHPMyInclude.php
     |
     -functions-|
                -TestFunctions-|
                               -PHPCallTestOnMyClass.php
```

so in PHPMyClass.php I do this:

```
<?php
    require_once '../includes/PHPMyInclude.php';
```

and if I test my PHPMyClass.php directly it works fine, e.g., it properly locates PHPMyInclude.php

however, if I attempt to include PHPMyClass.php in my PHPCallTestOnMyClass.php script, the load will fail since it can't find '../includes/PHPMyInclude.php' since it appears to be trying to reference this from the root of app/functions/testfunctions, which of course will not resolve properly. How do I manage locations in php layouts? I've resorted to taking the includes out of the sub files and hardcoding the includes into the  PHPCallTestOnMyClass.php code, e.g.,

```
<?php
    require_once '../../includes/PHPMyInclude.php';
    require_once '../../classes/PHPMyClass.php';
```

but this seems unnecessarily complicated and unsupportable. What am I missing?

I'm also running into this same problem when trying to use phpunit. There has to be something I'm just goofing up.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the full system path to the file to avoid this issue:

```
include("/path/from/root/to/inc/example.php");
```

A common thing to do is define a variable or constant that defines the root path to your web files. That way if it ever changes (i.e. you change hosts) you only need to change it in one place.

In your config file:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', '/path/from/root/to/');
```

In your PHP files;

```
include(ROOT_PATH . "inc/example.php");
```

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary to explicitly have to state the path to a file, and it isn't.

Comment: @Maniaque It's not necessary, but it's *smart*.

Comment: why is it smart? Why should I want to include the entire system file location in my includes? What would happen if it was moved to a server that wasn't laid out exactly as the original. Wouldn't that mean I'd have to edit every include statement?

Comment: No, because if you did it smartly (like I did above) it would be defined in one place only. Then you can move to a new server and only have to change your config file which you almost certainly would have to do anyway.

Comment: by "smartly" I'm assuming you're referring to the ROOT_PATH environment variable? Well yes, this definitely a better solution, but aren't you essentially reinventing the \__DIR__ variable?

Comment: No. But `__DIR__ is commonly used when defining `ROOT_PATH` as it makes it somewhat relative and allows you to move it more freely if necessary without breaking things.

Comment: Exactly. My problem with using a custom environment variable is anyone else wanting to use the code will be dependent on having to define this on their system too. Not a big problem within itself, but if it can be avoided every little bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

PHP relative paths are not relative to the files's location but the called file's location.

So, if you have an `index.php` file:

```
<?
include('includes/db.php');
```

An `includes/db.php`:

```
<?
include('user.php');
```

An `user.php` file:

```
<?
echo('root level');
```

An `includes/user.php` file:

```
<?
echo('includes folder');
```

If you access your `index.php` you'll see `root level`, since the include from `includes/db.php` is being called relatively to `index.php`.

Comment: Yes I understand this... which is why I adjusted my code to use the \__DIR__ "magic" variable.

Answer (score 0):

My solution of choice was to use the __dir__ [Magic constant as described here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

This allows me to use reference pathing as I would expect it...
For example:
require_once (__DIR__ . "/../enums/WorkUnitType.php");

will find the WorkUnitTypes.php file in reference of the directory of the php file it's being required from. This is exactly what I wanted.